# Copy Pasting Files with Absolute Path in Java on Linux

Tags: java, linux, filenotfoundexception

I keep getting a FileNotFound exception, however when I run it on Windows it works flawlessly. I ran a File.getAbsolutePath(); and it's returning the correct absolute path. What gives?

```
    if(os.equals("Linux")){
    File chrome = FileUtils.getFile("/home/kevinflynn/.config/google-chrome/Default/Login\\ Data");
    String path = chrome.getAbsolutePath(); // It's correct -_-
    File chromedest = FileUtils.getFile("/home/workspace/Crypt32/logindata.db");
    FileUtils.copyFile(chrome, chromedest);
    }

    else{
    File chrome = FileUtils.getFile("C:/Users/" + user + "/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/Login Data");
    File chromedest = FileUtils.getFile("logindata.db");
    FileUtils.copyFile(chrome, chromedest);
    }
```

I've tried a few different methods so far and made sure "Login Data" is 777'd
I'm running my IDE with root privs and all my other Java programs work fine.

chrome.canRead() still returns false, and copyFile trips the exception

Does FileUtils have issues with paths that are hidden or filenames that use escape characters?

Running Debian 8, Eclipse Mars

```
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Is there an *actual* backslash in the file name? I guess not - remove the double backslash from the path. You don't need to - and cannot - escape spaces in file names in Linux like this.

Comment: Yeh there is, sorry forget to mention that the actual file name is "Login\ Data", at least that's what it is in bash.